# Prove that the interior of a line segment joining two points on a sphere lies strictly inside of the sphere

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Practically if $|x|=|y| = r$ then $|(1-t)x + ty| < r$ for $0 < t < 1$.

But $|(1-t)x + ty| \leq (1-t)|x| + t|y| = r \Rightarrow |(1-t)x + ty| \leq r$

whats is the argumentation for this inequality be not strict?

Comment: Take any $x\in S.$ Then $-x\in S.$ The midpoint of $[-x,x]$ is the origin.

Comment: i know but i want a more formal and general prove. Can u help?

Comment: As you have stated the problem, a counterexample is all that is required.    Rephrase the question:  "Prove that  the interior of a line segment joining  two points on  a sphere  lies strictly inside of the sphere."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You invoked the vector property

$$|a+b|\le|a|+|b|.$$

You know that equality holds iff the two vectors are colinear and have the same orientation.

But $(1-t)x$ and $ty$ aren't, except in the degenerate cases $x=y$, $t=0$ or $t=1$.

Comment: i cant see why $(1-t)x$ and $ty$ are no colinear

Comment: @EduardoSilva Because $x$ and $y$ aren't.

Comment: because they are in the sphere?

Comment: @EduardoSilva: no, they are *on* the sphere.